# PowerShell - WMI returns incorrect profile last use time

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi, profile

I use Get-WMIObject with the Win32_UserProfile class and LastUseTime property to filter a Win7/Server2008R2 profile deletion script, and recently noticed that the date returned is not matching any of the applicable fields in Windows (Date Accessed, Date Modified, or Date Last Saved).

For example when checking a profile that was last accessed on 5/1/2015 at 1:54 PM per Windows, PowerShell returns the following:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName TESTCOMPUTER |      
    Where{$_.LocalPath -Like "*TESTUSER*"} |
    ForEach-Object{
        Write-Host $_.LastUseTime
        Write-Host $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime)}

20150502112839.854000+000
5/2/2015 4:28:39 AM
```

What am I missing?  I though it might have something to do with time zone, but the minute difference throws that off for me.  I've spent considerable time searching through Google, but haven't had any luck.  Any insight you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have time to down vote, please take the time to note why as well so I can learn from the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a program under the credentials of *TESTUSER* but without loading the environment this can happen. Both DateTimes aren't very accurate.
What do you mean with "last accessed? Logon, Logoff, ...?

Comment: I was referring to logon, but your question started me thinking about how often "Date Accessed" is updated. It turns out that NTFS can take up to an hour to update the accessed time (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx).  Thank you!